# Running Computing Python Scripts faster

Tags: python, performance

I am working on an optimization algorithm which I need to run at least 100 times to see its performance. The entire script is a straight loop script, running a specific set of code multiple times over. The problem is that this entire thing takes up to 10 hours on a small dataset.

Is it possible to run this on a platform so that I can decrease this time? Can I run it faster on the cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to you to "divide and conquer" your algo.
First, take a small sample of data in order to explore the code without lost too much time. After that you have a manageable piece of code, you can appy some kind of profiling tools to see where your time is spent.